# linux - how to run/execute a file in the command line without the ./

Tags: linux, file, execute

Let's say the file 'foo.sh' has all permissions and I just want to run the file in the current directory:

```
#> ./foo.sh
```

what/where could I change something in order to execute the file (any file with permissions) just by typing the name:

```
#>foo.sh
```

The idea would be that I could ALWAYS do this way (in the current directory). In case `./file.sh` is a valid way to execute a file, `file.sh` would work too. Not intended to run the `file.sh` globally.

Comment: Edit your `"$PATH"` variable to include the directory in which this file is located.

Comment: In your current shell you can do `PATH="${PATH};/new/dir/with/file" && export PATH` (this is for Linux)

Comment: You should know that there is a reason for the default behavior. It is safe not to run such things from the current directory, because then anyone could put a malicious file like 'cd' to any of your `$HOME` folder, and it will be called instead of original command. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65700/is-it-safe-to-add-to-my-path-how-come

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `"$PATH"` variable to include the directory in which this file is located.
For example, this is a part of my `"$PATH"`: */usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/rany/bin*

It includes the following directories:

- /usr/local/bin
- /usr/bin
- /bin
- /usr/local/sbin
- /usr/sbin
- /sbin
- /home/rany/bin

After putting an executable script in one of these directories you'll be able to execute it by simply typing its name at the command line.

After doing so, I suggest you to read this [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/081) for extra information.

Comment: the idea is to do this way in any directory, not only one in specific!

Comment: That's exactly what is going to happen, independent of the present current directory.

Comment: Any file where? In the current directory? If yes, then add `.` to your `PATH`

Comment: ...notice that this approach is unsafe. Check out  @Microfed comment on your question post.

Answer (score 0):

You can also copy the script under `/usr/local/bin` directory which is for user programs.

Comment: Well, shouldn't that more properly be `/usr/local/bin` if you are going to start randomly copying to the filesystem?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin you are right ! `/usr/local/bin` used for normal user programs. I modified the answer

Comment: the idea is to do this way in any directory, not only one in specific!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute this file specific to local user then create `~/bin` directory put the file inside of it and append this path to your `$PATH` env. ':' is a separator Check following link.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-adding-path/

But if you want to access this globally. Then place your file in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin and check are these paths already registered in `$PATH` then. Add your permissions. open new terminal try to call file.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add `'.'` to the path using: `export PATH=.:$PATH`

The above will run anything in the current directory. If you want to have this always present, add the above line to your profile.

Note that for some shells you may have to run two commands:

```
PATH=.:$PATH
export PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.` to your PATH so the shell will execute whatever it is in your current working directory. Something like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

After this, you can run `foo.sh` program by typing

```
$ foo.sh
```